# Determine the type of file on the internet from an android app

Tags: android

I am trying to develop an android MP3 downloader app which intakes a URL from the user and download the mp3 song to users device.How can my app determine if the requested URL contains an MP3 file or not?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'd start with issuing a HEAD request against the URL and checking the `content-type` response header. If it's `audio/mpeg` or anything that is not `text/something`, then it could be an MP3 file.

Comment: M trying this
String contentType = connection.getHeaderField("Content-Type");
boolean image = contentType.startsWith("audio/mpeg");

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at this site:

http://www.wotsit.org/list.asp?search=mp3&button=GO%21

You should be able to find out about the structure of MP3 files from there, giving you something to test against...

Comment: If you're going to downvote, that's fine, but a little explanation wouldn't go amiss...